# Spring+Redis About the Type of SystemEnv

Tags: java, xml, spring

Recently, i'm trying to access redis through spring.xml, but the host and port should get from System Propertities, so the xml as below:

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />   
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />   
 </bean>    

<bean id="redisClusterConfig" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisClusterConfiguration">
    <property name="clusterNodes">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisNode">
                <constructor-arg name="host" value= "${HOST}"/>
                <constructor-arg name="port" value="${PORT}"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
      destroy-method="destroy">
    <constructor-arg name="clusterConfig" ref="redisClusterConfig"/>
</bean>


<!-- redis template definition -->
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate">
     <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

it's ok, when i package it as jar and run in local, But when i put it to PAAS, "port" has some problems, the return of SystemEnv is String, but port should be int, how can i convert it in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
    <bean id="redisClusterConfig" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisClusterConfiguration">
        <property name="clusterNodes">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisNode">
                    <constructor-arg name="host" value= "${HOST}" />
                    <constructor-arg name="port" value="${PORT}" type="int"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```